# Пустая реализация методов класса

Tags: java

у меня есть 3 класса ObjectTypeA, ObjectTypeB, ObjectTypeC, моя задача вычислить скорость. У этих классов скорость зависит от разных наборов параметров, например
у ObjectTypeA скорость зависит от параметров height, viscosity (вязкость) и lenght
у  ObjectTypeB скорость зависит от параметров height и lenght
у ObjectTypeC скорость зависит от параметров height, lenght, density (плотность) и startFlow ( стартовый расход)

Кроме того скорость в каждого объекта зависит от скорости которую ему передал соединенный  с ним объект, причем все три типа объектов ObjectTypeA, ObjectTypeB, ObjectTypeC могут соединяться друг с другом (механизм соединения тут не принципиален)

Я хочу сделать строитель с помощью которого можно построить объекты любого класса из трех, для этого я хочу сделать интерфейс

```
public interface ConstructedObject {

 void setLength(long length);
 void setHeight(long height);
 void setViscosity (double viscosity);
 void setDensity (double density);
 void setStartFlow (double startFlow);
 void build();
}
```

Соответственно сделать строители каждого объекта реализующие этот интерфейс
чтобы мне потом не привязываться к конкретным классам строителей а привязываться к интерфейсу, как то так:

```
 public class ObjectBuilder(){
    public ConstructedObject  CreateObjectTypeA(){
       return new ContructObjectTypeA()   
      }
   }

   //Use in main code
ObjectBuilder objBuilder= new ObjectBuilder();
ConstructedObject cObj=objBuilder.CreateObjectTypeA()
cObj.setLength(5);
cObj.build();
```

Но при таком подходе при создании ObjectTypeA у меня будет пустая реализация методов `void setViscosity (double viscosity); void setDensity (double density); void setStartFlow (double startFlow);` ну и соответственно для других объектов будут встречаться пустые реализации методов. В связи с этим вопрос, является ли такой подход допустимым? С одной стороны неправильно вызывать метод setViscosity там где он не имеет смысла и если добавится еще один объект с новым свойством, которое добавится в интерфейс придется переписывать все классы реализующие этот интерфейс, с другой стороны получается более жесткая привязанность к конкретным классам.

Я не могу представить как пересмотреть данную архитектуру, т.к. в рамках задачи объекты ObjectTypeA, ObjectTypeB, ObjectTypeC связываются друг с другом внутри другого объекта ObjectCalculateVelocity и по сути своей для него они все одинаковы, т.к. предоставляют ему метод getVelocity() из интерфейса CalculatedVelocity.

Comment: CreateObjectTypeA что за наименование метода...

Comment: сделай интерфейс в котором будут общие методы и возвращай этот интерфейс

Comment: Вопрос то в том, насколько плохо сделать общий интерфейс для трех объектов, но при этом реализацию некоторых методов этого интерфейса оставлять пустой, ведь ConstructedObject cObj=new ContructObjectTypeA() будет иметь методы  cObj.setDensity() который в принципе ничего не делает и он не нужен по идее для этого объекта

Comment: Плохо конечно , если разработчик решит дёрнуть этот метод, а он окажется пустышкой. по моему так себе будет... Либо используй интерфейс с общими методами, которые точно будут реализованы имплементирующими классами, либо используй несколько интерфейсов с наследованием

Comment: плохо, однозначно. запомните простую вещь: интрефейс определяет клиент (класс, который делает вызов), а не класс, имплементирующий интерфейс. сделайте интрфейс для вычисления скорости - общий и нужный для вызова. таким образом обеспечите Low Coupling, а создание и инициализацию классов выполняйте с помощью стандартного паттерна фабричный метод

Comment: Так и сделано относительно интерфейса вычисления скорости. Я хочу сделать именно низкую связанность при создании объекта.Сейчас я использую строитель, а не фабрику. Как я себе это представляю, пользователь получает строителя для каждого объекта А, В или С, задает доступные ему свойства (setLength, setDensity например), вызывает метод build() для добавления этого объекта к модулю вычислений. У меня получается под каждый объект свой строитель и их нельзя объединить общим интерфейсом. Поэтому тут я и стою перед выбором, отказаться от Low Coupling у строителей или делать методы пустышки.

Comment: Методы пустышки это явное следствие нарушения одного из принципов SOLID.